# gps trace visualizations

Tags: dictionary, networking, visualization, traffic

I have about 2-3 months of GPS trace data. Basically, of about 30-40 vehicles moving across the city each day - and points popping up when they sync up with the satellite.

I want to make a speed up animated video of these cars moving over the 2-3 month period in about a minute.

Any advice on if there are good python libraries to do this? Basically, points popping up and then going off - to show gps traces and all the car/tracks that are moving.

Comment: You can probably try http://avtanski.net/projects/gps/ although it is written in Perl.